# Code examples for SmartTarget in JSP?

Tags: smarttarget, jsp

The docs contain a [detailed TCDL reference](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-2E35D309-1457-48BA-A591-AE1E2BABA8BA) for SmartTarget tags, however I am not rendering my pages at publish time, and want to use the JSP tag libs directly in my page view code. Does anyone have some examples to get me started - I would have guessed to just use a similar syntax to the TCDL, but there seems to be some differences (TCDL has a region tag, but the taglib not, for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shortest possible SmartTarget promotions implementation with JSP tags is as follows. This indeed looks a lot like the TCDL tags.

[source](https://gist.github.com/0b313b9d0fb1b3eb1f2b)

```
<smarttarget:query siteEditTagName="span" publication="tcm:0-72-1"> 
    <smarttarget:promotions region="Homepage Banners" maxItems="1"> 
        <smarttarget:itemTemplate> 
            <smarttarget:promotionalItems> 
                <smarttarget:itemTemplate>
                    <span>
                        <!-- Start Promotion: { "PromotionID": "${item.promotionID}", "RegionID" : "${item.region}"} -->
                        <tridion:ComponentPresentation pageURI="tcm:72-6212-64" componentURI="${item.componentUri}" templateURI="${item.templateUri}"/> 
                        <!-- End Promotion -->
                    </span>
                </smarttarget:itemTemplate> 
            </smarttarget:promotionalItems> 
        </smarttarget:itemTemplate> 
    </smarttarget:promotions> 
</smarttarget:query>
```

Here are some other examples, all are showing the same thing: one SmartTarget region which queries for promotions, Eperience Manager Markup and three fallback component presentations.

- Full JSP example: https://gist.github.com/83e45c851b63481e39bb This the
- TCDL source: https://gist.github.com/3b5c48c3a5ea5d5e12b8 The
- Dreamweaver source: https://gist.github.com/6053b09d0ccbd31e058b And
- The same thing in .NET controls instead of JSP tags 
  https://gist.github.com/70d569023e78081c3b57

The `<tcdl:region>` tag in the Dreamweaver TBB creates the TCDL source. The TCDL tags create the JSP tags. The JSP tags creates the HTML output with XPM markup ([example](https://gist.github.com/ea7312358ce22a61bbea)).

Answer (score 4):

There is a TLD file on the CD layout (Content Delivery\java\web\tld) which provides the list of tags, their attributes, and remarks explaining the purpose of each of them.

Combine that with the [API documentation available on LiveContent](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-0DFCF420-270B-4EA8-B8F8-C2E0FD99A8EF) (login required) and you should have a complete picture on how to use the tags in your web application.