# smarttarget.tld issue with 9.5

Tags: smarttarget, java, sites-9.5

When I add XO to my live website in 9.5 I need to register smarttarget tags according to [this link.](https://docs.rws.com/816112/589481/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/registering-custom-tags-in-java-based-page-templates)
However, then I get the following exception in logs:

Msg: Error while looking for TLD file for "http://www.sdl.com/smarttarget/2.0"; see cause exception.

```
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #assign smarttarget = JspTaglibs["htt...  [in template "40/tcm:40-xxxxx/tcm:40-xxx-32/not_mobile" at line 1137, column 17] [END] 
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Error while looking for TLD file for "http://www.sdl.com/smarttarget/2.0"; see cause exception.
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #assign smarttarget = JspTaglibs["htt...  [in template "40/tcm:40-xxxxx/tcm:40-xxx-32/not_mobile" at line 1137, column 17]
    at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.get(TaglibFactory.java:246)
```

**However, in 8.5 I used smarttarget.tld file to add it locally in my app and reference it from there, but in 9.5 installation it is not there.**

Old tld file for 8.5 is not working because some classes are removed in later versions so using that causes missing class exception.

Does anyone has any idea where to find new smarttarget.tld file, or how to reference it in java app?

Comment: you can find the  tld file under Content Delivery\java\web\tld on the SmartTarget 2014 SP1

Comment: refer the kink for more details https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/code-examples-for-smarttarget-in-jsp

Comment: yeah, that does not work for 9.5. tld file is not there in 9.5 installations. that is the whole purpose of my question

Comment: yes i understand smarttarget.tdl was part of Experience Optimization installer web 8.5 and its no longer part of the Sites 9.x installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smarttarget.tld` tag lib is contained in `\Content Delivery\roles\xo\api\rest\java\lib\xo-query-client-tags-11.5.0-XXXX.jar`.

Comment: yeah, paul brou from customer support provided me with the info. thanks for it also